# Random number generator PCG library. How to generate float numbers set within a range. Working example in c language

Tags: c, random

For example, we can use internal rand(), but it is the worst choice:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

float randoms(float min, float max)
{
    return (float)(rand())/RAND_MAX*(max - min) + min;
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    printf("%f\n",randoms(-100.001, 100.001));
    return 0;
}
```

I've searched, but not found any working example of PCG library for float numbers.

In the answer I would like to share my own experience of using PCG random library to generate float numbers within a fixed range. Previously I've used arc4random library for this goal, but PCG is simpler and has no complicated dependencies.

Comment: Is the generator allowed to draw `max`?

Comment: This looks like "let me show you how to use a simple function from some arbitrary library fully documented [here](http://www.pcg-random.org/using-pcg-c-basic.html#pcg32-srandom-r-rngptr-initstate-initseq) and some basic math".

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There is nothing wrong per se in sharing something that a user could find with some effort. It is even encouraged in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @SergeBallesta Nothing wrong, yet the question itself should be useful and comply with other SO standards.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Please, show where there you can see an example of float numbers in range in official documentation? Yes, this is simple example, but demanded in applications and could be useful for newbies. Or you think it is not required for anyone?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I did not advocate whether it is a good question, just reacting to the comment. IMHO it looks like an honest attemp to share knowledge. As far as I am concerned I will neither upvote (nothing that concerns me) nor downvote (nothing specially poor)

Comment: @SergeBallesta If it was a genuine question, I would comment it like something "this function is fully documented in <placeholder>", since it doesn't, the comment is coming in the corresponding form, that's it. I am not criticizing the will to share of knowledge, but not of any arbitrary and basic knowledge. We won't get away too far if everyone will post basic facts as QA.

Comment: @DennisV.R.: Please do not be offensive. I really think it is an honest attempt, but your question (and anwser) is about simple (linear) integer range to float conversion without addressing more complex parts like max and min drawing (cf Batsheba's comment) nor eventual precision problems which soon come with random floats. It is not by accident if random libraries only return integers. So Eugene may honestly think that your posts have little added value. Try to improve them, when you will have more experience on this site.

Comment: DennisV.R. The question by [@Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228749/random-number-generator-pcg-library-how-to-generate-float-numbers-set-within-a/48230129#comment83439581_48228749) is quite relevant as often the `max` endpoint is not part of the valid return values like `randoms(0.0, 1.0f)` to get values in the [0...1) range.  When generating FP values in a range, it is important to specify the edge conditions.

Comment: Concerning  [@EugeneSh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228749/random-number-generator-pcg-library-how-to-generate-float-numbers-set-within-a/48230129#comment83439602_48228749) comment, the "basic math" part is glossed over in OP's question. `rand()` vs _PCG random library_ is only 1 part of the issue here and IMO, the lesser issue.

Comment: @EugeneSh. With all due respect, but it is "basic fact" only for you, with all your experience. Not for me, or any other newbie, who try to find working example for libraries, which have been developed by representatives from the rocket science. :)

Comment: @SergeBallesta Well, thank you for understanding all this. I'm just at the very beginning of the programming path. Unfortunately, it is extremely difficult to find answers to many of my questions. Now I understand that my example has many math problems. I would like to thanks you and averyone others for comments and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

> How to generate float numbers set within a range(?)

Using various random functions can improve the random properties of *integers* generated.  The application of those integers to make a `float` has other pitfalls not address by OP regardless of the random function.  Also see [@Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228749/random-number-generator-pcg-library-how-to-generate-float-numbers-set-within-a/48230129#comment83441105_48228749).

---

The simplistic use of the following risks generating a value outside the range [min...max]

```
float retval = (float)some_rand()/SOME_RAND_MAX*(max -  min) + min;
```

The 2 conversion of the 2 integers to `float` incur rounding.   `float` `/,*,-,*` each can contribute 4 more roundings.  Given that `min/max` may come in many valid combinations, it is prudent to guard against an out-of-range `retval`

```
float retval;
assert(min < max);  // may want to assert min/max are finite too
do {
  retval = 1.0f*some_rand()/SOME_RAND_MAX*(max -  min) + min;
} while (!(retval >= min && retval <= max));
return retval;
```

Note that the setting of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` complicates any assessment as some calculations may be conducted as `double/long double`.

---

Potential losses of desired random properties:

The use of `pcg32_random_r()` versus `rand()` does provide numbers with more attractive *integer* random properties, yet those improved attributes are reduced with casual floating-point code.

(Assume [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) for `float`)

Consider how the following can uniformly generate values in the range [0...2<sup>24</sup>] yet values larger than that, it will be only even numbers.  It becomes spottier with larger numbers up to `(float)UINT32_MAX`.  This would be acceptable for another function that was now to return that value, but the scaling of `*(max -  min) + min` redistributes those values in a way that can become very *non-uniform*.

```
(float)pcg32_random_r(...);
```

A simple way to address some of these short comings is to use higher precision like `double` math within `float randoms(float min, float max)`, yet that approach does not help with `long double randomsL(long double min, long double max)`

Answer (score 1):

You PCG will generate some number of random bits. Let's say that's 32. A double precision float has 53 bits of significand, so you'll need more than one call. So, call the function twice, and pack the two calls into a 64-bit integer:

```
int64_t x = (pcg32() << 32) | pcg32();
```

Then divide that integer down to the desired range (this is the signed -100...100 version):

```
double r = ((double)x * 100.0) / 9223372036854775808.0; // 2**63
```

Comment: For double precision PCG [suggests](http://www.pcg-random.org/using-pcg-c-basic.html#generating-doubles) solution like this:
`double d = ldexp(pcg32_random_r(&myrng), -32);`

Comment: That will work (and probably faster), but only gets you 32 bits of precision.

Answer (score 0):

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

// PCH library headers
#include "pcg_variants.h"
#include "entropy.h"                    // Wrapper around /dev/random

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pcg32_random_t rng;

    // Seed with external entropy
    uint64_t seeds[2];
    entropy_getbytes((void*)seeds, sizeof(seeds));
    pcg32_srandom_r(&rng, seeds[0], seeds[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        uint32_t random_unsigned_integer = pcg32_random_r(&rng);
        float max = 100.001;
        float min = -100.001;
        float q = (float)(random_unsigned_integer)/((float)UINT32_MAX)*(max - min) + min;
        // Shows 10 float numbers in specified range.
        printf("%.6f\n", q);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -std=c11 -o pcg_float main.c
```